# 410: Prepare statement failed or was not executed

Tags: prepared-statement, informix

In an informix database I can't run a simple query like "select * from customer;" because
after running this query, I get this error:

```
410: Prepare statement failed or was not executed.
Error in line 1
Near character position 23
```

Can anyone help me?

I killed all sessions and at last rebooted the server, but it doesn't work for me.
There is no "prepare statement" and I couldn't find anything helpful after 2 days of searching the net.

Comment: There are so many details missing it is impossible to help you.  What language are you writing your code in?  It might be ODBC, JDBC, ESQL/C, or some other language built atop one of these.  Which platform are you running the code on?  Which platform is the Informix server running on?  What is the sequence of statements that you use?  Without a lot more relevant information, I don't see how we can easily help.

Comment: The `finderr -410` program reports: _-410 Prepare statement failed or was not executed._ / _This EXECUTE statement refers to a statement id that has not been
prepared. Either no PREPARE statement was done, or one was done but
returned an error code. Review the program logic to ensure that a
statement is prepared and the PREPARE return code is checked. A
negative error code from PREPARE usually reflects an error in the
statement being prepared._. This sounds like ESQL/C, but that isn't completely a given — and if it is ESQL/C, we need to see the code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: I'm not the programmer. I'm a dba and developers used jdbc connection to connect to database and their program language was java. after running some codes with hibernate i faced this error and killed the sessions. is it needed to connect to the database again and run codes with hibernate again?

Comment: we all are using linux redhat 8

Comment: Is there any exceptions or errors reported prior to this -410? I would presume if JDBC/hibernate are throwing a -410 either 1) A prior execution failed and would show in the java logs, or 2) the server has an error in it's log file that indicates why the statement suddenly is not executable.